# CXX0017: Error: symbol not found in static library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When I try to watch some variables in a static library linked with current startup project I receive this error:

```
CXX0017: Error: symbol not found
```

I've tried to rebuild the project/close IDE but I have same error. I can use breakpoints/step/other features.

Do you have any idea why is this happening? Maybe some weird compiler flags or else...

Edit: Only some variables can't be viewed in debugger! In general local variables.

Comment: It seems like a VS2010 bug. [See here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613569/cannot-inspect-local-variables-while-debugging-in-vs2010-cxx0017-symbol-not-found-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/8d1007d4-c85a-44e8-970a-1c2a7b638ce4

> please check whether pdb file have loaded properly from correct
>   project folder, you can select **Debug -> Windows -> Modules**, on the
>   Modules window, right click the symbol item, select Symbol Load
>   Information, from the pop up window, you can see whether the pdb file
>   is loaded and where the pdb file is loaded from.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Cplex solver and I had this problem, I changed the following setting to "disabled(/od)":
from property pages > configuration manager > c/c++ > optimization >optimization
and now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I have bumped in to the same problems, and I'm using VS2005. About changing the setting to(/od) in the Projects - propoties - C/C++ Optimization and failed.
Then, I found Souce File and right click the file then click propoties, in this page I found another C/C++ Optimization and chose /od. It helps.